# How to click a box with selenium which i can't see its element?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, iframe, screen-scraping

I want to change the frametime in fxblue technical analysis from 1h (the default value) to 5m but i can't click its pop-up button.
here is the code i tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver')  
url = "https://www.fxblue.com/market-data/technical-analysis/EURUSD"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
timestamp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TimeframeContainer"]').click()
```

at this point I can see the pop-up with the timeframes but I couldn't find a way to change the timeframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements in the `Timeframe` pop-up is in an `iframe`. Need to `switch to frame` to interact with the elements contained in it.

```
# Imports required
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.fxblue.com/market-data/technical-analysis/EURUSD")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Click on timestamp button.
timestamp = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtTimeframe")))
timestamp.click()

# Switch to iframe.
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@class,'DialogInnerIframe')]")))

# click on M5 button.
fivemin = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='TimeframeItem' and text()='M5']")))
fivemin.click()

# Switch to default content to interact with other elements.
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on that element opens a dialog.
So you need to select and click the desired element on that dialog.
The dialog is in iframe, you have to switch to that iframe.
After selecting the desired option and the dialog is closed you have to switch back from the iframe to the default content.
Also you should use explicit wait instead of hardcoded pauses.
Your code may be something like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver')  
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.fxblue.com/market-data/technical-analysis/EURUSD"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "TimeframeContainer"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.DialogDragBar")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@tf='300']").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the lovely script, I had some issues from my end on the same and this code snippet helped me solve them

Made some small tweaks with the logger and sharing the same for benefit of the community

```
"""
@author:  ""
@copyright:  ""
@credits:  [""]
@license:  ""
@version: ""
@Date: "" 
@maintainer: ""
@email: ""
@status: ""
@Function: "To scrape data from fx blue for technical analysis"
"""

import logging
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os.path
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Define the URL of the webpage to scrape
url = "https://www.fxblue.com/market-data/technical-analysis/"

class WebScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = url
        self.driver_path = os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver'  # Path to Chrome driver executable
        self.logger = self.setup_logger()
        self.now= datetime.now()
        self.dt_string = self.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")        


    def setup_logger(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger("WebScraper")
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        
        # Create a file handler to log the execution status
        log_file = f"logs/scraper_logs_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')}.log"
        
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # Create a formatter for the log messages
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-15s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        # Add the file handler to the logger
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        #print(log_file)
        return logger

    def parse_data(self):
        try:
            service = Service(self.driver_path)
            chrome_options = Options()
            #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
            driver.get(self.url)
            time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occurred during fetching page:", str(e))
            
        
        # Add code to parse the HTML content and extract the data
        self.dt_string = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        
        '''
        main functionality begins here
        '''
        
        now= datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        results = []
        '''
        instrument = ["AUDCAD", "AUDJPY","AUDUSD","CADJPY","EURGBP","EURJPY","EURUSD",
                     "GBPUSD", "USDCAD","USDJPY","XAUUSD","WTI","BRENT",
                     "SP500", "NAS100","DJ30","ASX200","HK50","JP225","FTSE100",
                     "DAX", "BTCUSD","ETHUSD"]
        timeframe = ["M30", "H1", "H4", "D1", "W1"]
        '''
        instrument = ["AUDCAD", "AUDJPY"]
        timeframe = ["M30", "H1", "H4"]
        try:    
            for ins in instrument:
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver')  
                url = "https://www.fxblue.com/market-data/technical-analysis/" + str(ins)
                driver.get(url)
                wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
                time.sleep(5)
                for tf in timeframe:
                    # Click on timestamp button.
                    timestamp = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtTimeframe")))
                    timestamp.click()
    
                    # Switch to iframe.
                    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@class,'DialogInnerIframe')]")))
    
                    # click on M5 button.
                    fivemin = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='TimeframeItem' and text()='%s']"%tf)))
                    fivemin.click()
                    
                    result = {}
                    buy = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='TAScoreLabel']")
                    buy = [x.text for x in buy]
                    #print(buy)
                    value = buy[0]
                    result['instrument'] = ins
                    result['buy'] = value
                    result['Timing'] = tf
                    result['timestamp'] = dt_string
                    results.append(result)
                #print(results)
    
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.quit()
            return results
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.warning("Failed to scrape data from the URL.")
            print("Error occurred during data parsing:", str(e))
            return None
        #close the driver 
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

    def execute(self):
        self.logger.info("Execution started.")
        scraped_data = self.parse_data()
        if scraped_data is not None:
            #print(scraped_data)
            # Create a DataFrame from the scraped data
            
            df = pd.DataFrame(scraped_data) # Each list would be added as a row
            #df = df.transpose() # To Transpose and make each rows as columns
            
            try:                
                df.to_csv('fxblue_technical_analysis_%s.csv'%datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'),  mode='a', index=False)
                self.logger.info("Data processing and save complete.")
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.warning("Failed to save - :",e)
            
            # Process the DataFrame as needed
            self.logger.info("Data processing and save complete.")
            #self.logger.info("Scraped data:")
            
        else:
            self.logger.warning("Failed to save")
        self.logger.info("Execution finished.")
        
        

# Create an instance of the WebScraper class
scraper = WebScraper()

# Execute the web scraping process
scraper.execute()
```